# Edit stylesheet provided by bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I am supposed to continue the developpement of an app started with someone else.
This app isdevelopped using spring mvc, hibernate, My SQL. For the front-end bootstrap is used, but not showing in the project directory structure, so when I eed to change something in the view where should I be working ?

[This is the project directory structure :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46jUW.png)

and this is the part of jsp page where the stylesheet is called :

```
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
```

Comment: You shouldn't (usually) edit the Bootstrap CSS, you just need to override it in your own CSS file.

Comment: To override it, I should add link to an other stylesheet right ?

Something like that :


    <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="/bootstrap/css/overrideStylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Yes, that should do it, but if it's an existing project, I'm betting you already have a site CSS file somewhere.

Comment: I didn't find bootstrap stylesheet in the project directory structure, I guess because they used webjars